# Apply condition row by row in array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python so this might be an easy question. Sorry if that's the case!

I have an array `a` and I would like to known which values each row of `a` are lower or equal to a value in the same row as `b`.

```
a = np.array([[8,1,7],[4,3,9],[5,2,6]])
b = np.array([[7],[4],[6]])
```

The resulting array should be:

```
c = np.array([[False,True,True],[True,True,False],[True,True,True]])
```

I've tried:

```
np.where((a <= b), True, False)
```

and

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.where((a <= b), True, False),1,a)
```

None of them work.

Comment: What about `a <= b`?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
s = np.where((a-b) < 0, True, False)
print(a[s])
```

Would this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is great for doing element wise logical operation!

In this example a simple`a<=b` should do the job. You can learn more about it here https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (14,31) (14,)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

The problem was that the array b was not fully defined: shape was (x,).
I reshaped it to be (x,1) and then  everything worked.

Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

```
c = [lambda x, y: x <= y] 

c(a,b)
```